# Returning variable in main fuinction

Tags: c, return

Can I return a variable in main function? like in

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int factorial,int n)
{
    n=1;
    printf("Enter a number to find it's factorial: ");
    scanf("%d",&factorial);
    while(factorial!=0){
        n*=factorial;
        factorial--;
    }
    //printf("%d",n);
    return ("%d",n);   //Here
    return n;          //neither works
}
```

It doesn't return the variable *n*. Is the **return 0;** statement only for telling that the program worked fine?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: it doesn't have my answer.

Comment: Your last assumption is pretty close: it's telling the environment whether the program finished ok (return 0 usually) or with an error (return non-0 value). Otherwise, where should main() return to anyway?

Comment: How does the linked question not have your answer? The accepted answer starts with "The return value for main should indicate how the program exited.". That is pretty much the answer you're looking for.

Comment: If you want to tell the environment the result of your calculation instead (which is what you seem to be asking), just print the value.

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze your code step by step...

```
int main(int factorial,int n)
```

Function `main` takes two parameters: `factorial` of type `int`, and `n` of type `int`, and returns an object of type `int`. **Error: *`main` is a special function, and the only valid signatures for it are `int main()` and `int main(int, char**)`, or any compatible type thereafter, such as `int main(int, const char *const[])`***.

```
{
```

Begin function `main`.

```
    n = 1;
```

Assign value `1` to variable `n` of type `int`.

```
    printf("Enter a number to find it's factorial: ");
```

Call function `printf` with argument `"Enter a number to find it's factorial: "` of type `const char*`. The variable-length argument list is empty. The function's return value (of type `int`) is discarded.

```
    scanf("%d", &factorial);
```

Call function `scanf` with argument `"%d"` of type `const char*`. The variable-length argument list contains one argument: `&factorial`, of type `int*`. The function's return value (of type `int`) is discarded.

```
    while(factorial != 0) {
```

While `factorial` is not equal to `0`, do.

```
        n *= factorial;
```

Assign `n` the result of multiplying `n` by `factorial`.

```
        factorial--;
```

Decrement `factorial` after the expression, and discard the expression's value (of type `int`).

```
    }
```

End while block.

```
    //printf("%d",n);
```

Comment line. Has no effect on the program.

```
    return ("%d",n);   //Here
```

The expression `("%d", n)` uses the comma operator to evaluate the `"%d"` expression, then the `n` expression, and evaluating to the latter, effectively ignoring the former. Thus, this is equivalent to `return n;`.

```
    return n;          //neither works
```

Since the previous return statement has already been ran by this moment, this is dead code that will never be executed. Anyway, it's equivalent to the previous return statement.

```
}
```

End function `main`.

Now, with the obvious exception of the wrong `main` signature, and the dead code at the end, you're completely right. And yes, if the return value of `main` is zero, the program is said to have executed successfully. Otherwise, it executed unsuccessfully, and the purpose of the return value is to provide (broad) information about what went wrong.

I hope this has led a light on you!

Answer (score 1):

The return value for main should indicate how the program exited. Normal exit is generally represented by a 0 return value from main. Abnormal termination is usually signaled by a non-zero return but there is no standard for how non-zero codes are interpreted.

> Is the return 0; statement only for telling that the program worked
>   fine?

Yes, the return value of main function only shows how program is exited, no other use with this value as you do with return value of non main functions like return a value for other uses.

The returned value is interpreted by environment (like DOS or other operating systems) from which the program is running for it's internal tasks. The program can't use that value.